# pass a bundle of hashmap to a fragment

Tags: android, hashmap, fragment

I have two classes, one extends `FragmentActivity` and the other extends `Fragment`.

I want to pass a hash map in a bundle to the Fragment class from the `FragmentActivity` class. The `Fragment` Class should draw a graph (through graphView library) based on the hash map values it receives from the `FragmentActivity` class and that graph would be displayed inside the "fragment" part of the `FragmentActivity` xml file. I want to invoke the `Fragment` class on a `Checkbox` i.e. A hashmap should be passed to the `Fragment` class when a certain `CheckBox` is checked. Below is my code which does not show any errors but it doesn't work either. I tried a very small fragment example, which worked but I cannot make it work in my actual application. I'd be grateful for any help.

```
public class Graphs_Combination extends FragmentActivity {
// some other code
public void onClick(View v)
{
        Fragment fr;
        fr = new DrawSingleGraph();

        if (((CheckBox) v).isChecked())
        {
            ListOfCheckedFctrsNames.add(((CheckBox) v).getText().toString());
            displayCheckedTextViews(ListOfCheckedFctrsNames);

            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putSerializable(((CheckBox) v).getText().toString(),mMap);

            fr.setArguments(bundle);
    }
}
```

}

```
public class DrawSingleGraph extends Fragment {
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,
          ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.draw_single_graph,container, false);
    Log.e(LOG, "Inside DrawSingleGraph");

    Bundle b = this.getArguments();
    if(b.getSerializable("Depression") != null)
        mMap = (HashMap<String, HashMap<String,String>>)b.getSerializable("Depression");
```

}

It doesn't even show the Log message which doesn't depend on the bundle.
Many Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You created your `Fragment`, but didn't do anything with it beyond that.  You have to get a `FragmentTransaction` via the `Activity`'s `FragmentManager` and add the new `Fragment` appropriately.

Comment: Thanks Larry, I'll try to do it the way you suggested.